# Code never pass trough $.each (element, ...) ($.each cycle is never invoked)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this code:

```
function iterateChoices(row, element, choices, counter) {
    if ($.isArray(choices) && choices.length > 0) {
        element.each(function(index, item) {
            if (counter === 0) {
                row = '<div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">UPC:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pupc[]" /></div>';
                row += '<div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Precio:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pprice[]" /></div>';
                row += '<div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Cantidad:</label><input type="text" style="display: inline-block" value="" name="pqty[]" /></div>';
            }

            iterateChoices(row + '<div style="display:inline-block"><input style="display: inline-block" disabled="disabled" value="' + item.value + '"></div>', choices[0], choices.slice(1), counter + 1);
        });
        console.log("Counter: " + counter);
        console.log("Row: " + row);
    } else {
        html_temp = "";
        element.each(function(index, item) {
            html_temp += row + '<div style="display:inline-block"><input  style="display: inline-block" value="' + item.value + '" disabled="disabled"></div><br>';
        });
        html += html_temp;
    }
    console.log("html_temp: " + html_temp);
}
```

I test what `element` has as values:

```
$.isArray(element)
false

element.length
2

element
[
<input type=​"text" name=​"input_color[]​" class=​"field_color" data-id=​"color_5" placeholder=​"Color">​
, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"input_color[]​" class=​"field_color" data-id=​"color_5" placeholder=​"Color">​
]

$.each(element, function(index, item) { console.log(item) })
<input type=​"text" name=​"input_color[]​" class=​"field_color" data-id=​"color_5" placeholder=​"Color">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"input_color[]​" class=​"field_color" data-id=​"color_5" placeholder=​"Color">​
```

This is the output of each `console.log()`:

```
html_temp: 
Counter: 1
Row: <div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">UPC:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pupc[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Precio:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pprice[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Cantidad:</label><input type="text" style="display: inline-block" value="" name="pqty[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><input style="display: inline-block" disabled="disabled" value="Red"></div>
html_temp: 
html_temp: 
Counter: 1
Row: <div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">UPC:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pupc[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Precio:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pprice[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Cantidad:</label><input type="text" style="display: inline-block" value="" name="pqty[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><input style="display: inline-block" disabled="disabled" value="Blue"></div>
html_temp: 
Counter: 0
Row: <div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">UPC:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pupc[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Precio:</label> <input style="display: inline-block" type="text" value="" name="pprice[]" /></div><div style="display:inline-block"><label style="display: inline-block">Cantidad:</label><input type="text" style="display: inline-block" value="" name="pqty[]" /></div>
html_temp:
```

For some reason in the real code it never goes trough `$.each(element, ...)` and I can't find where the error is, any help or advise?

**UPDATE**
I created [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggcwz/1/) for testing purposes, how it works:

1. Mark any of the chekboxes
2. Add as many as inputs you want for each set of options (color, talla)
3. Click on "Create variation" button

Behavior: if yours check the latest checkbox things works as I want, if yours don't then code stop and never get the results as I want

**UPDATE 2:**

I added some `console.log()` statements just when function is called and see results:

```
function iterateChoices(row, element, choices, counter) {
    console.log("element: " + element);
    console.log("choices: " + choices);
    console.log("counter: " + counter);
    ...

element:  
[input.field_color, input.field_color, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#color_choice_5 input:text", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
choices:  
[x.fn.x.init[1], x.fn.x.init[0]]
counter:  0
element:  
[input.field_talla, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#talla_choice_6 input:text", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
choices:  
[x.fn.x.init[0]]
counter:  1
element:  
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#talla_choice_13 input:text", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
choices:  []
counter:  2
0
element:  
[input.field_talla, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#talla_choice_6 input:text", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
choices:  
[x.fn.x.init[0]]
counter:  1
element:  
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "#talla_choice_13 input:text", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
choices:  []
counter:  2
0
```

Really don't know where it fails

Comment: You are doing `$.inArray(choices)` and then `$.each(element`.  Why?

Comment: The `$.each` isn't being called because `$.isArray` returned `false`.  It's probably a jQuery object, which is not an array.  Lose the `$.isArray` call and see if that helps.

Comment: @RocketHazmat sorry, updated in main post I'm refer to `$.each(element`

Comment: @RocketHazmat how do I convert element to a array? I've tried `$.toArray()` but didn't work

Comment: isn't it say that your `element` is not an array, hence it doesn't pass first `if`?

Comment: @Elen hmm this is rare since and if you notice I tried the same code at console and it works since it iterate trough element values

Comment: @RocketHazmat already try that and still not working since it never goes trough `element.each(function(index, item){});`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't go through"?  How do you know it's not?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I mean it never enters in `element.each(function(index, item) {` because it never create the elements inside the cycle meaning the input that you see there

Comment: If you `console.log(row)` or `console.log(html_temp)` after the `each`, what do you see?  What is the value of `counter`?  Your first loop only "works" `if (counter === 0) {.

Comment: @Reynier Put a `console.log` or `alert` on the first line inside the `each` - there could be other issues stopping elements being created. Just test the loop is being entered with a simple debug statement first.

Comment: @Reynier can you setup [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP see main post I edited with results since can write them here

Comment: @Unknown I'll try, let you know in a few minutes

Comment: Your `console.log("html_temp: " + html_temp);` is in the wrong spot.

Comment: element.each(function(index, item) {}); Try it like $.each(element,function(index,item){});

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli this is how I have before and didn't work either

Comment: What is `iterateChoices` supposed to do?  It doesn't return anything or update the DOM.  In your code, as you can see your `row` is being updated, so the `each` loop *is* running.  As for `html_temp`, that loop will only run if `element` has something in it.  Try to `console.log(element.length)`, and you'll see it's `0` (before the `html_temp` loop).

Comment: When you use `console.log` *don't* use the `+`.  This converts everything to a *string*!  Use `,` instead.  `console.log('element:', element);`.

Comment: `iterateChoices` should return some values and update the DOM see this call `$('#choices_picker').on("click", "#create-variation", function(e) { ...`, but what is wrong since it never get values as should be? For example if at least one input exists then I should be able to generate variations for this one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56vx9/ check this out

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli how this can help me?

Comment: I can see it's being logged in console, but I cannot see where do you actually output the result to DOM? You don't return anything?...

Comment: @Elen is here `$('#choices_picker').on("click", "#create-variation", function(e) { ... }` take a look at that code and you'll see where I update the DOM

Comment: No.... you don't write anything to DOM.... your `html = "";
        iterateChoices("", element[0], element.slice(1), 0);
        $('#variations_holder').append(html);` appends **empty** string... function `each()` returns `object` and code so messy, I lost interest